# Make a new dictionary, removing some keys and without changing the original

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

What's the quickest way to make a new dictionary (minus one key) out of an old one without changing the original?

e.g.

> input= {potato : 10, book2 : 182, book17 : 12}

make a new dict without book2 without changing the original input

> returning = {potato : 10, book17 : 12}

Comment: Manually, but I assume that's not what you meant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

copy first

```
d_returning = dict(d_input)
```

Then delete

```
del d_returning['book2']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
returning = {k: v for k, v in input.items() if k != 'book2'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d= {'potato' : 10, 'book2' : 182, 'book17' : 12}
print(dict([(key,d[key]) for key in d if not key=='book2']))
```

Output:

```
{'potato': 10, 'book17': 12}
```

Or better:

```
d.pop('book2')
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'potato': 10, 'book17': 12}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d= {'potato' : 10, 'book2' : 182, 'book17' : 12}
d.__delitem__('book2')
print(d)
```